# Adding a date element in GregorianCalendar ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist, gregorian-calendar

I'm having trouble when I input many date elements, all the other elements become the last date I input.

SuperClass:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
String year = "1995", month = "12", day = "24";
GregorianCalendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month), Integer.parseInt(day));

public void addDate(int month, int day, int year){
    date.add(startDate);
    startDate.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    startDate.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, year);
    startDate.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, month);
}
public String printCal(int i){
    return sdf.format(date.get(i).getTime());
}
public void addName(String newName){
    name.add(newName);
}
```

Sub-Class:

```
for(i=0; i<emp.emNum(); i++){
                System.out.println("Name: "+ emp.printName(i) + " Date Joined: " + emp.printCal(i));
            }
```

**Output**

For example, 2 element inputs):

```
Name: John, Date Joined: December 25, 2000

Name: Peter, Date Joined: December 25, 2000
```

Comment: if i don't make a mistake, you have to put the "new GregorianCalendar" in your addDate method

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! This came to me for review (all first posts go to a review).  I edited out the bit at the top ("All your answers worked thanks"...).  Not because I'm ungrateful or unfriendly (I hope), but because on here the best way to say thanks is to give upvotes on answers that worked for you and accept the one that you used.  Saying thanks in questions / posts is generally discouraged on here - although its often the subject of discussion (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109956/is-it-important-to-say-thanks-after-getting-correct-answer) for example)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of `GregorianCalendar` each time you wish to add it.
In java when you add something to a List you basically only add a reference to an Object. If you modify it using get(i), you will modify the Object

```
public void addDate(int month, int day, int year){
    date.add(new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month), Integer.parseInt(day));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the object startDate and this is your problem. You need to create a new instance of GregorianCalendar for each new record.

```
public void addDate(int month, int day, int year)
{
    GregorianCalendar myDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    myDate.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    startDate.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, year);
    startDate.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, month);
    date.add(startDate);
}
```